# Is it good to do Cross Validation with the exact same dataset that is used in training phase?

Tags: validation, machine-learning, weka, cross-validation, supervised-learning

I am using Weka API to test the performance of some algorithms. If I want to divide the dataset as following:

- 70% for training
- 10% for validation
- 20% for testing

For the validation phase, should I use the cross validation method on 10% divided fresh data? Or is it better to apply cross validation on the 70% data that has already trained? And why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is actually very problem specific, but in general - it depends on the **size of the dataset**. If you have big dataset then even a subsample is representative, thus you can split everything once to train/valid/test and just run a typical optimization and testing routine. On the other hand, if you have rather small datast (~1000 samples) then actually both testing and validation require CV (or other technique, like err 0.632). It is all about statistical significance of obtained error estimates. If data is small - you need to generate multiple experiments (CV) to get a reasonable estimator; if you have 100,000 samples then even 10% should be enough to use as a valid estimator of error.

Comment: So, do you mean that it is always better to do validation on different data (from training) when the dataset is big enough?

Comment: I mean that if it is big enough than **it is sufficient** to do it once, on separate validation set. This is purely **efficiency** based reasoning. Simply you will not get significantly better results by CV, and you will use 10x more computational resources.